# Ubuntu 12.04 installation with windows8.1 pre-installed

Tags: 12.04, installation, uefi

I have a laptop with windows8.1 pre-installed. Now I want to install Ubuntu12.04 and don't want to remove windows. I have disabled window8.1 FastStartup. In my BIOS, I can't find fastBoot or quickBoot.

Then I tried several times, it always show the error "the grub efi package failed to install into target". It drive me crazy. Anyoone knows how solve this?

Comment: did you change UEFI mode to legacy mode in bios?

Answer (score 0):

If the Ubuntu installation has mostly completed, I recommend you try one or both of the following:

- Download a USB flash drive or CD-R image of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html), prepare a disk, and boot from it. You should see options for both Windows and Linux. If both work, then you can install the Debian-package version in Linux and forget about GRUB.
- Run the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool from an Ubuntu live CD. This should install a fresh copy of GRUB, finishing what the Ubuntu installer failed to do.

If both of these fail, then post back with the URL that Boot Repair provides, along with a description of any errors you see from both approaches. That will give us more information about what might be going wrong, enabling a better diagnosis.